# How to calculate speed with steps and distance TYPE_STEP_COUNTER

Tags: java, android

I need to calculate speed with the information of steps and distance cover !
Can anyone please guide me how can i do that one way i think of as using formula 
`S = VT` but in this case i need time per step in order to calculate the `velocity` per step ..I have already looked at stackoverflow but did not solve the issue.
Thanks.

In this block of code i am calculating step count by TYPE_COUNTER_STEP and distance by taking person height and multiply it by 0.45 and then multiply it with steps

public void registerForSensorEvents() {
    SensorManager sManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

```
// Step Counter
sManager.registerListener(new SensorEventListener() {

                              @Override
                              public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                                  float steps = event.values[0];

                                  arrayList.add((int)steps);
                                  getCurrentStepValue = (int) steps ;
                                  stepValue.setText(getCurrentStepValue - arrayList.get(0) + "");

                                  double distaneCovered = step_length * (getCurrentStepValue - arrayList.get(0));

                                  distanceValue.setText("" + distaneCovered);


                              }

                              @Override
                              public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

                              }
                          }, sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

}

Comment: Yes you need time information. What accuracy do you need? Did you consider `getTime( )`? It should allow millisecond resolution, at least in the returned value; not sure that you can really read each millisecond. What reasons against that do you have? What frequency of steps are you expecting?

Comment: The accuracy to calculate the steps is very good and with steps i am calculating distance by multiplying 0.415*person height but i do not figure out how can i get time as per step !! Can i get time using STEP_DETECTOR ?

Comment: What step frequency do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You should take an initial stamp with first step, in second step take the difference between "now" and initial stamp, then you'll have time/step, reset initial stamp to "now" and do the same in following steps.

As well you can simply have a timer and calculate number of steps (so distance) in X seconds instead of having time/step, it would depend on what you really need to do.

Comment: if i calculate time as you mention and i already have no of steps ! How can i get the distance by it as you said ? It does not make any sense

Comment: Avila thanks for you suggestion i applied the method but  my time difference value is very small in seconds and when i get the velocity using s= vt i get infinity .. Any idea